# how can i unlock my locked screen of lg p 500

Tags: sim-unlocking, volume

my screen locked after too many attempts but my volume key is also not working for hard reset. can any body have idea? due non working condition of my volume keys i am unable to hard reset.

Answer (score 1):

The hard reset would be a sensible thing to do in this situation but if the volume keys are broken then it won't work (as you mentioned already). However, sometimes you just need to push them a little harder.

Try turning your phone 180degrees and pressing them.
   If all fails, you are left with no option but to take it into a store where the keys can be fixed (to be honest why wouldn't you, having a phone without volume buttons is like having a radio without volume knob).
   It won't cost a great deal of money to get it fixed and will ensure quality for years to come, otherwise just get a new phone.